# TypeError: table.count is not a function

Tags: protractor

IN protractor **non-angular** gives me

> TypeError: table.count is not a function

```
await element(by.xpath(`//div[@id='${identity}']/table/tbody/tr`)).isPresent().then(async() =>{
  await table.count().then(async (val) => {
    console.log(`Total number of ${identity} :` + val);
    expect(val.isPresent()).to.be.eventually.true;
  });
});
```

Comment: You are not declaring the variable `table` anywhere in your example

Comment: Yes, write us what your `table` is tag me in the comment when done

Answer (score 0):

```
let identity = '<put the id here>';

let rows = element.all(by.xpath(`//div[@id='${identity}']/table/tbody/tr`));

let count = await table.count();

console.log(`Total number of ${identity} :` + count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in a dark, since your question is incomplete, the problem may be that `count()` method may be executed against elementArrayFinder and your table is an elementFinder -

either `table = $("...")` or `table = element(by...("..."))`

whereas it should've been an elementArrayFinder -

either `table = $$("...")` or `table = element.all(by...("..."))`

Thus if you update your answer and include the code of your spec where you declare `table` it would be easier to help you